# System is shutting down instead of hibernating

Tags: 12.04, shutdown, hibernate, hybrid-graphics, catalyst

I have an HP g4-1387, core I5, 4Gb RAM, 8Gb swap and hybrid Intel/ATI graphics with Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS.

Finally after installing AMD Catalyst 12.4 as described [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450/) I was able to Suspend. Hibernate and shutdown. With any other version superior to 12.4 my system hangs on shutdown, hibernating and suspending. Now it works but I am not able to hibernate correctly. When I do it I see disk activity "saving" my data, but when I turn on my computer again I get login screen and everything is gone, the system seems to shutdown instead of hybernating. I use this to hibernate:

```
sudo pm-hibernate
```

My kernel version is `3.2.0-36-generic` according to `uname -r` and I have plenty free swap when I try to hibernate (almost all my 8Gb).

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved it. The problem seemed to be that I had /home and swap partitions encrypted. I tried to desencrypt the partitions but the problem persisted. So I did this:

1. Backup my data (home folder in my case)
2. Fresh install formatting /home and / partition
3. Install ATI Catalyst 12.4 (not higher because it cause problems)
4. Everything is working!